# Changing button titles from different .m files

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am writing some code that works in several languages. When the user changes the language I need to change all the screen prompts and button text. When I am in the .m for that screen I simply type:

```
    [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Setup"];
```

But how to I change the prompts in the other screens without having to go to each .m and make the changes. I am assuming that "self" can be replaced to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use localized strings. Something like this might help you find the right path:
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Basically, instead of using strings like `@"Setup"` you'll use something like this

```
[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:
           NSLocalizedString("setup_button_title", "Title for the setup button")];
```

Comment: What I have works. What I want to do is change the button titles on another screen. Does this make sense?